# How to copy files from remote to host ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy files from a remote host to my local server where I am running Ansible playbook. Though the task always executes successfully but the file is never copied to local server. Here is the code:

```
- file:
    path: vm_info.config
    mode: 0777

- fetch:
    src: vm_info.config
    dest: .
    #flat: yes
    fail_on_missing: yes
```

I tried copy module as well but none of them is getting me the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [fetch - Fetches a file from remote nodes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fetch_module.html)

> dest - A directory to save the file into. For example, if the dest
>   directory is /backup a src file named /etc/profile on host
>   host.example.com, would be saved into
>   /backup/host.example.com/etc/profile

So look in `./remote-host/vm_info.config`. For example, your remote host is 192.168.1.3, the fetched file will be: `./192.168.1.3/vm_info.config`

If you had used **-v** option, it would have printed the location of the fetched file. I ran the playbook from /tmp directory.

> TASK [fetch]
>   ******************************************************************* changed: [192.168.1.99] => {"changed": true, "checksum":
>   "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "dest":
>   "/tmp/192.168.1.3/vm_info.config", "md5sum":
>   "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e", "remote_checksum":
>   "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "remote_md5sum": null}

```
root@ip-192-168-1-99:~$ ls -l /tmp/192.168.1.3/vm_info.config
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 0 Dec 16 23:58 /tmp/192.168.1.3/vm_info.config
```

Comment: Great Answer, Thank You!