# How to copy a file from a remote windows host to an ansible control server?

Tags: ansible

I want to copy a file from a remote *windows* host to the local ansible server.
I have searched stackoverflow but I only found answers for Linux host : [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193929/how-to-copy-files-from-remote-to-host-ansible) Unfortunately the `fetch` seems not to work with windows hosts.

**So how can I copy from a remote windows host to a local ansible server?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure it out, and I have to revert my initial statement. The error messages where miss leading. The fetch module *does* work also for Windows. I my case I had a bad winrm connection. But instead of an error message the module tried to connect via ssh and finally ended "ok" (green!) the only indication that it did not worked that the file was not copied -- and this never could have happened since the was no ssh connection. I reinstalled the winrm and all worked fine!! Here is the working code:

```
   - name: Fetch war file from buildserver
      fetch:  
        validate_checksum: yes
        src: "{{ war_file_path }}{{ war_file_name }}" 
        dest: "{{ warfile_tmp_folder }}"
        flat: yes    
      delegate_to: "{{ buildserver }}"
```